# What comment should I add to code-only answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement

While [code-only answers should not be deleted while reviewing Low Quality Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300694/3453226), I would like to add a comment for the user explaining how they can improve their post.

I'm seeking input and discussions from the community to best write it.

These are my thoughts. You can use italic formatting to highlight specific keywords.
Feel free to propose something completely different.

1. > While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some *context*, explaining *how* it works and *when* to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.
2. > While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain *how* it solves the problem without introducing others and *why* to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: 3. Give the man a fish *then* teach him *how* to fish.

Comment: _Code-only answers are not useful in the long run._ -- I do not agree that this holds true without context to the question and answer. In some cases it may be a valid criticism but in others it may stand alone just fine.

Comment: Set a fire for a man, warm him for the evening. Set a man on fire, keep him warm for the rest of his life.

Comment: @OhBeWise Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It was a whimsical ode to the quote, "*Give a man to fish, feed him for a day;  teach a man to fish, feed him for life.*" But essentially, give a code answer and you've helped the asker this time. Explain the code and now maybe with the understanding of the how's and why's, he'll figure his next issue out on his own. In seriousness, I like Dave's suggestion.

Comment: A blob of code on the internet without a single word of explanation is of limited usefulness because anyone who encounters it in the future will have to copy/paste the code and execute it to see what it does. Not many people are willing to do that. So, when I comment on a code-only answer, I usually try to point this out, and ask that the author clarify what their code does and how it relates to the problem statement in the question.

Comment: Instead of either of those comments, I would suggest you ask specific questions about what you don't understand. If you can't come up with a good question, it must be pretty self-explanatory. No code only answer is completely without context since the question provides context.

Comment: @ChrisBaker Decent code is expressive, and can be read without running it.  Then there's regular expressions.

Comment: I don't see code-only answers as a problem from an understand-ability point of view - good code can be read and shows what it's trying to do. My only problem with it is that it A) can suggest you should copy/paste it and not adapt it at all, and more importantly B) avoids giving any additional keywords for reading up more about the solution. Even just a one-liner can help dramatically "this can be solved with a list-comprehension (followed by code)", etc.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In my opinion, this depends entirely on context: over-explaining is at least as bad, if not worse.

If it's short, the code may *be* the best explanation possible.

1. > While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
2. > While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @pnuts Yep, I hear that. That's not a generality I'll adhere to, but I get the sentiment. I'm just not convinced all code-only answers are inherently bad.

Comment: I think a code-only answer can seem appropriate when it appears self evident how to use the code.  However, many people LEARN to code by reading SO answers (ahem, your truly) and thus benefit from a little bit of explanation of even the "obvious."  I agree with @DaveNewton but would say that MOST of the time a bit of vernacular clarification helps :)

Comment: I'm intrigued by *over-explaining is at least as bad*. "man this answer contains far too good a description of the how to solve the problem"...said no one ever :)

Comment: @Liam I'd disagree. Some answers ramble, address interesting but irrelevant points, and so on. New users in particular often over-explain. Too many words can be confusing, overwhelming, and make answers harder to understand.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree under the context of mixing *"trivia"* with the main explanations, but disagree otherwise. First, even (potentially useful) trivia is welcome ***if separated from the answer***. And while *"any answer that gets the **asker** going in the right direction is helpful"* ([answer]), they should not assume that (all) the **reader(s)** is (/are) going to be familiar with the Programming-Language and/or APIs being used. And should explain *why* the answer's code works, at least as *in-code comments*. Remember: ***Good code** is **documented enough** for **everyone** to understand.*

Comment: @DaveNewton As an example of how properly separated *"trivia"* can be a *plus* rather than a *minus*, here is [one of my answers that included *"trivia"*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34477932/1253136). --- Notice how the stuff that is not directly related to the answer is *separated* from the rest, is *put last* on the content of the answer-post, and is only *briefly mentioned where appropriate* within the answering sections of the post (*"Note: I explain (...), in the second item of the 'side notes' section."*).

Comment: @AlmightyR You sure like using various forms of highlighting; it makes these comments much harder to read. Most "good code" is self-documenting: documenting "enough" doesn't automatically mean "commented". "Trivia" *may* be helpful, but isn't automatically: repeating information found in regex documentation and tutorials crosses that line for me. YMMV, but I'd prefer to keep canonical documentation that already exists in its existing location.

Comment: @DaveNewton The problem lies with what an experienced programmer might think is *"self-documenting"* enough, and that new programmer may not find so intuitive. That's the standard displayed by most *code-only* answers (at least the ones I've seen). And if the code is *"simple"* enough to be considered *"self-documenting"*, wouldn't it also be simple enough to be commented (without being *"over-commented"*?) I think (good) code-only answers with no comments *are still inappropriate*, although not enough to deserve down-vote or deletion. And they all should receive a recommendation to improve.

Comment: @DaveNewton As for *"I'd prefer to keep canonical documentation that already exists in its existing location"*, I generally agree in principle, but not always in practice. While simply linking to external documentation or articles avoids including such *trivia* in the answer, it makes assumptions I am not really either comfortable with, nor a fan of: 1) Assuming the reader doesn't *"hate links"* (Paradox: *"Might not know he/she'd like to read through, before actually reading through"*). 2) Assuming the linked content will remain the same. 3) Assuming the link itself will (keep) work(ing).

Comment: @DaveNewton I recognize that some of the problems raised by these inevitable assumptions when linking are mitigated by the fact that failing links (either by changed content or by dead servers/sites/links) can be, and probably will be fixed through future editing by members of the SO community, if such problems happen. But that still doesn't cut it for me personally. I'm the *"better safe than sorry"* kind of guy.

Comment: @AlmightyR If the code is simple enough to be self-documenting then *additional* comments are noise, by definition. And another potential point of failure. Unrelated, but when you're using italics *and* quotes, it doesn't always render in a way that makes reading easy.

Comment: @DaveNewton If the code's definition as *"simple enough to be self-documenting"* is ambiguous (and as I explained, it is), then *comments* that help to clarify the context of the code are *useful*, by definition. And, unless exaggerated, a *likely* point of *success* (as an answer). --- Unrelated: Quotes shouldn't affect format, so it's probable that you find *italics* hard to read. And I can't know for sure, but, they were *also hard for me before I got used to them*, so maybe that's the case?

Comment: Too often do I see code-only answers using the shield of "my snippet is self-explanatory / self-documenting" after I ask for some explanation. They often forget that the researchers may be unaware of the language/technique supplied.  Remember that questions and answers are never 1-to-1 interactions. The whole purpose of SO is to educate/empower thousands of future researchers. The fact that the two people immediately concerned (asker & answerer) understand what is happening is a mere drop in the bucket. Always add _something_ to your snippet if not for any other reason than role modeling.

Comment: When SO has the "problem" of being over-whelmed with "over-explained" answers, we can certainly cross that bridge when we come to it but I doubt that day will ever come.  While we still have FGITW posters, we will need to defend this site from snippet droppers.

Comment: I like the wording and will use it with low rep users.  However, I just saw a high rep user post a code only answer.  It was correct, but not helpful because one needed to dig deep into the code to understand what was fixed. Others downvoted the answer and that is probably the only response needed.

Comment: @Yogi It’s very context-dependent ‍♂️

Answer (score 27):

I’ve recently discovered this type of comment which I like better than [the recommended ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/711006).

> Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Here is the markdown code so that you can copy-paste it (use triple-click to select it):

`Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.`

Credit to [@Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight). (I modified his text slightly.)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a comment I have copied from an expert:

> While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

I usually use it in an answer that is provided by some user who has ***more than*** 300 reputation points (there isn't any need to say *Welcome to Stack Overflow*).

I don't use this quote as a comment to some user who has *less than* 300 reputation points, because it looks like a *heart-attack*, and I usually start with *Welcome to Stack Overflow! ...*

---

These are some tests:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 3):

> Code-only/Unexplained answers are low-value and miss an opportunity to educate/empower the OP as well as thousands of future researchers. Please [edit] your answer to include one or more of the following non-code insights: an explanation of how/why the code works, fringe case considerations/caveats/pitfalls, reasons why this snippet may be more ideal than another technique, and relevant documentation links. If you feel this is the best possible solution, then be compelling about why. Help researchers to identify the solution that they *should* use among the solutions that they *can* use.

...phew, 5 characters left!

Whether or not my suggested comment is ideal, it is important that we explain *why* answerers should post more than code.  We need to find a clear, poignant message which:

1. explains that they are not only speaking to the OP, and
2. has a high success rate of spurring a positive edit, and
3. will trigger them to adopt this mantra and put them on a path to writing better/complete answers without any new external motivation.

I, personally, do a fair amount of duplicate hammering in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag pool.  I care about the quality of pages that I put forward as the dupe target.  When I have a choice between multiple duplicates, I am far less likely to nominate a page with unexplained answers to a new question because the goal is to educate the new OP.  So, in these cases, code-only answers impact *my* efforts and slow me down while I search for a page with high quality insights.

The whole community improves when we have better crafted content in more places.  The more contributors we have who are posting complete answers, the more normalized the practice becomes -- so grows a better community.

Comment: So.. not only does a researcher, as you call them, have to figure out why a solution works. They also need to read though this huge comment :D

Comment: I am happy for it to be reduced without losing its meaning.  The comment is intended to be "disposable".  After the answer is updated, the comment should be flagged for deletion.  Sometimes I get a reply to my comments.  When this happens, I delete my comment and if the answer is unique, correct, and "helpful/insightful" I upvote the answer.

Comment: Personally I use "How does it work?" or "What is it doing?". I've not had all that much success with it, but I'm not sure it's the length of my comment that's the culprit.

Comment: If those pages, contained more of the gist of my provided comment, I'd be more inclined to just refer folks to those pages. (would make things much simpler for everyone)  I wish `[answer]` went farther to indicate that closable questions should not be answered and why.

Comment: ...I should also state that my personal set of SO principles precludes me from upvoting a code-only answer -- even if I found it helpful.  It would be counterproductive to reward a post that does not align with what I consider to be good posting behaviors.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be following a rule just for the sake of following a rule. Why not leave a comment saying something like "I upvoted this answer because it's useful, *despite* the fact that code-only answers are [explanation of problems]... Please don't take this as an indication that such answers are generally acceptable"?. That would send the message that you want, while also sending the signal that the answer is useful via the upvote. Note that votes are not rewards/punishments, but a signal of the usefulness of a post.

Comment: Right, well, by my criteria a code-only answer does not score high enough on my "usefulness scale" to warrant an upvote.  Sometimes I say that I would upvote an answer if it was it was explained.  Upvotes not only convey the usefulness of a single post, they also contribute the "trust" metric.  If contributors want me to vouch for their trustworthiness, they need to post good complete answers.

Comment: Ah, I see. I read the "... even if I found it helpful." and imagined that if you found a post to be "helpful", that would also mean that you found it "useful". No worries, I just misunderstood your comment. You can of course vote as you see fit, as always. I didn't know about this "trust" metric that you use, that's quite interesting. I hadn't thought of it like that. I tend to just vote on whether it's useful in solving the problem or not.

Comment: This is not a place where we **educate** people though. And I don't think code-only answers are low-value at all, this canned comment is both misleading and condescending.

Comment: Pfft. You lost me at "_This is not a place where we educate people though._"  Why are we here then? Unicorn point farming?

Comment: Kudos for finding duplicates. It is one of the most important activities on Stack Overflow (and also the most difficult).

Comment: The call to action is good (*"Please edit your answer"*), but if users come from a forum background (where traditionally ***nothing*** can be changed after posting, not even the first few minutes), they may have ***no idea*** what "edit" is (a completely unknown concept, not just the word). "Change" may be a better word to use. Also, [a live link to change the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/404884/edit) may help.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Adding even a comment is already going above and beyond what is necessary. If a user actually wants to help, it's their responsibility to make their content helpful.

Comment: @IanKemp I do not downvote code-only answers unless they are giving bad advice (or I'd run out of downvotes).  If I make no comment, then there is nothing to spur positive growth. A comment is essential if I hope to see any improvement in the post and in the user's posting behaviors. I am not a "bare minimum" type of volunteer.  I regularly go "above and beyond" when curating.  This is how good stuff happens. We need more people going above and beyond what is required in this world. Peter, adding `[edit]` is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The comment should:

1. Start with a direct statement that there is a problem.
2. Acknowledge the potential usefulness of the provided code.
3. Explain why something other than code is desirable.
4. Link to relevant meta or help pages.
5. End with a call to action for the user to edit the post and improve it.

I don't like some specific phrasing used by others:

- Starting with a apologetic couching statement isn't helpful.   When delivering bad news, it is better to be direct up front.  The first sentence should state what the problem is without apology.  Softening the blow in a later sentence is fine once the problem statement is out of the way.
- "This code may answer the question" implies that a code-only answer is an acceptable answer.  Instead I would say "this code may be useful."
- "Proper answer" isn't descriptive enough to be actionable.
- "And/or" can usually be replaced with just "and" or just "or" without losing meaning.

Here is what I will be using:

`[A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.`