# Should I downvote answers that contain no explanation?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, low-quality-posts

I see this post: [Get a specific value from comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035156/get-a-specific-value-from-comma-separated-string/34035260#34035260)

And there are two answers which are just code and do not provide any explanation. The OP just says that "use this" or "do that" and shows the code. I don't think these answers are good quality. If I were the asker and saw such answers, I would not understand why should I "do this" or how the method does the job.

I think it is very unclear to write answers like this. But one answer got two upvotes! Why? IMO these are like one-liner answers!

On the other hand though, it really *did* answer the question. So I am not sure if I should downvote it. If not, what should I do?

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate because the possible duplicates are concerning code-only and code with comments. What I mean is in general, if it is juts an answer that solves the OP's problem, no matter is it with code or without code. Answers like:

Create a string array to store XXXX.

Comment: From two answer one answer had link for the method, which broadly describe the method. And the OP says that "Use this method" to split. It means it is the one of the answer. To know more about the method any one can search that method on search engine and get the details. Here code explain everything.

Comment: Lots of good information here (including links to previous discussions about this topic): [To curate or to not curate - questions about code-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311079/4639281)

Comment: Votes are opinionated expressions on the content of the post. if *"this answer was useful"* for ***you*** then vote it up. if it wasn't then vote it down. if you have no opinion then don't vote.

Comment: @Sweeper, your edit contradicts the first two sentences of your second paragraph (hence the duplicate). You may want to fix that.

Comment: In those cases, I generally add the following comment: "Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution."

Comment: This may be a better dupe: [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers while blocking code-only questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272)