# Is it better to answer beginner's questions with intro-level answers?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I have come across this a lot in my first few weeks on Stack Overflow: Often times users who are obviously (and often self-proclaimed) beginners to a specific concept are met with often over-complex answers that they struggle to grasp.

It seems to happen quite too often that answers are Code Golfed-- finding the simplest and most elegant solution to an issue. However, this is almost never the most readable solution and often uses concepts a beginner has not yet come across.

My question for discussion: Is it better to answer beginner's questions with intro-level concepts, or attempt to teach more advanced methods all together? How can this best be managed by a community of experienced developers?

Comment: I feel like there are two related but separate issues here: answers that use advanced / elegant / professional techniques to do what's requested, and answers that don't *explain* what they're doing. The combination can be problematic, but surely the problem is in the lack of explanation? See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311079/to-curate-or-to-not-curate-questions-about-code-only-answers

Comment: @Shog9 I feel like there exists answers that can do both and still not be ideal for the OP's question. I guess the question becomes: Is attempting to teach a beginning user an obviously better advanced technique better than answering the question using things you know they will immediately understand?

Comment: That is a very different question than the one you asked.

Comment: I don't know if **very** different is the right word, more of just adding information to the prompt. Answering in a way that is entry-level and one that the OP will obviously understand is an approach that will work and often provides the most efficient ask->answer interface. However, should users prioritize teaching an advanced technique over the entry-level method all-together, or is this not the goal of SO?

Comment: it's important to actually answer the question. Past that, it's not important whether you use "advanced techniques" (whatever that is...) or not. Just note that the harder it is to understand your answer, the less likely someone will find it useful.

Comment: Teaching is not the goal of SO.

Comment: Indeed, SO is a trigger to learn, not a place to teach. In cases such as this "Oh I don't know this concept that is demonstrated in this answer, I better go learn about that". Of course that is not how people who are there to outsource a problem think, but those people are on the wrong site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kinda sorta *really* depends on what you're answering.

I answer questions with a presumed level of understanding; depending on the question, I gauge that at anywhere between, "understands what they're doing with this framework" to "understands how syntax goes", but this is mostly internal and only tied to key words in the OP's question.

The only time I've shied away from answering a question in a less complex fashion is if the OP clearly states that there are constraints.  Other than that, I will use and leverage any technique that I feel is appropriate and viable to solve the problem clearly and concisely.  I don't dumb down for beginners; if they're asking a question that *mandates* that I bring out lambdas or regex, I expect them to be prepared for that.