# What can I do about very low quality answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

The reason for this post is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14640716/1839439).

> [image]

I have encountered answers like this multiple times. An answer posted three years later to a question which already has an accepted or highly-upvoted answer. Sometimes it is code-only, and sometimes there is some explanation attached. It does not qualify to be flagged as [NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420), but it also doesn't have any value for others. It either contains multiple errors, uses deprecated extensions (e.g. `mysql_*` functions in PHP), or is simply suggesting a solution much worse than the existing ones. I can only downvote to show my disapproval, but if it is an old post one vote is unlikely to change anything.

I have no option to vote for deletion, I can't edit it to make it better, and none of the flags apply. The only option left is to flag for moderator's attention, but I believe such issues should not be handled by moderators. I remember that in past there was an option to flag as [VLQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420), but even then I wasn't sure if it would apply to situations like this.

> [image]

P.S.: The only valuable answer in that post is the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: Downvote it. Code only answers aren't 'very low quality', and if it attempts to address the question it's an answer. Downvote it.  Moderators only intercede to delete answers that meet one of our flag criteria; and "covers same ground as another answer" isn't a reason for us to delete it.  Plagiarism is, however.

Comment: I agree if it is code-only, but still an attempt then yes. However, this example here I am not even sure what was meant to be. Is is plagiarised from comment section in php.net? Why is the code commented out? What is THE SOLUTION?

Comment: "What can I do about very low quality answers?" Weep for the future of programming? That's about it. You could do a search for one of the lines of code using a site-specific search like "site:php.net echo ..." or whatever to see if it's plagiarized. You could also stop looking at PHP questions, but I digress ;-P (hey, I frequent `javascript` -- I lost faith a long time ago).

Comment: @Dharman all good questions and all the more reason for you to downvote it if that's how you feel about it. The problem with asking moderators to intercede is that you're asking people who aren't experts in PHP to determine whether an answer that is in PHP should stay around. We can't make those sorts of judgments on answers (unless a particular moderator happens to have PHP experience).

Comment: This is exactly why I said: "I believe such issues should not be handled by moderators".

Comment: Agreed with George here, this answer doesn't adds any more meaningful information to the question (the answers there are sufficient) and is a code only answer. Flagging it for VLQ is not optimal, instead, [leave a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers), we can just downvote and move on

Comment: @weegee I do not have the option to flag as VLQ. I do not think that adding a comment is going to improve things. It's not like the person who cared so little about the answer at the time, is going to come back 6 years later to add explanation.

Comment: @Dharman you cannot reach out to everyone and make them read the comment you just did, what most can you do it to leave a comment and tell the user to do "this" the very next time, If they don't learn, you cannot do anything.

Comment: Post it on Meta and wait for people to delete it. Roomba may also get it, if you downvote it enough and wait.

Comment: @JL2210 roomba only gets question with all it's answers but 20k users can surely delete it, since it's downvoted.

Comment: Conclusione downvoted, get to 20k, delete vote and if it's really really bad post del-pls request in SOCVR

Comment: @PetterFriberg To bad it's a pain in the a$$ to get enough rep to get to 20k.

Comment: @JL2210 already down voting you help, slow and steady you will arrive

Comment: @JL2210 You can keep downvoting answers just like me, and get -1 rep each. Soon you will reach -20k

Comment: I was hoping to get to +20k, so I can post a [del-pls] in SOCVR...

Comment: @JL2210 you can do that without 20k but yeah need to have a particolare good reason and it needs the be downvoted (hence possible to delete)

Comment: This seems to be plagiarized from somewhere (the first portion of the code is identical to one of the other answers). Who *knows* where the second part could've come from (probably php.net).

Comment: Overall however remember that the main problem of SO is bad questions a downvoted answer amongst other upvoted once does not do damage (it only shows how not to do :)

Comment: Backing up George's statement (also a possible dupe): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/6296561 - That being said, "I got this solution from php.net" could point to possible plagiarism (the full source isn't listed, and the code is probably copy-pasta)

Comment: @Zoe citing your source is what makes it not plagiarism.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker By that train of thought I could say: "I got it off the internet" and get away with plagiarism. Even when cited the domain, we still are wondering where he got this piece of code from.

Comment: @dharman I didn't write the definition for plagiarism. ‍♂️