# What source should I cite to a new user suggesting a code-only answer is not ideal?

Tags: support

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) does not ask about a source. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), but it doesn't seem to address the issue. Is there an authoritative source which says you should not post code-only answers?

Comment: [This question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5395/is-there-a-consensus-on-whether-answers-should-contain-explanations-of-code) has a nice discussion on the topic, but it is on a different SE website (unix.se).

Comment: [Why are code-only answers not considered “very low quality”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354280/3001761), [Low quality posts and code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345719/3001761)

Comment: The help center article hints at it with "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution. See the highest voted answer.