# Review Ban based on low quality answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

It happened twice to me, I get banned while reviewing test answers, the thing is I am really paying attention but for some reason the community has different opinion.

Here is an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18155485

[image: voted up answer with low quality]

I flagged it as low quality answer, because it has no explanation or what so ever that describes this code.

Should not be like some criteria for test reviews?

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354280/why-are-code-only-answers-not-considered-very-low-quality

Comment: @abccd I believe its https://stackoverflow.com/a/47151887/4826457

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18155485

Comment: Also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300694/what-to-do-with-code-only-answers-in-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: To refrain from the links, when encountering code-only answers, you should write a comment stating how adding some more textual details might benefit the answer. Please **do not** vote to delete them since an answer is still an answer, and can potentially solve the problem (or at least be useful) for many viewers.

Comment: @abccd I'm pretty sure that just commenting will already make you fail the review, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313666/3266847

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code only answers are sometimes not the best, but that doesn't mean that they should be deleted.

If the answer solves the problem, somebody may find it useful.

When reviewing/flagging answers, you shouldn't be checking if it is a great answer, the decision is whether the answer should be deleted or not.